# How to convert from numbers in string to its hexadecimal value?

Tags: .net, hex, type-conversion

I have a text file (test.txt), with hexadecimal data in it, when i open it, it looks like:

test.txt:
`00 FF 0F 00` ...etc.

I read them in with .NET:

`byte [] in = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:/test.txt");`

At this point, i can see my string as:

`in[0] = 0x30 // first 0
     in[1] = 0x30 // second 0
     in[2] = 0x20 // space
     in[3] = 0x46 // F char
     ...`

I'm ok with deleting every space and \n\r characters, but i wish to have a sipmle one line conversion for 0x30 to 0x0 and 0x46 to 0xF

OR

A one line solution to transform a string with:

`string s = 00FF10` to `byte [] a = 0x0, 0xFF, 0x10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read contents of the file as a `string`, split it, then parse each part as byte.

Example without input validation to make it simple:

```
var bytes = "00 FF 0F 00"
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => byte.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
    .ToArray();
```